# How to mimic `Get-AzureADUser` in C#

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on an Azure AD B2C application and the B2C policy stores the MFA secret-key in the `extension_mfaTotpSecretKey` property of the user. This works and when I run `Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId '<object-id>' | ConvertTo-Json`, then it shows:

```json
{
  "ExtensionProperty":  {
    "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/<tenant-id>/$metadata#directoryObjects/@Element",
    "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
    "createdDateTime": "2/4/2022 2:13:22 PM",
    "employeeId": null,
    "onPremisesDistinguishedName": null,
    "userIdentities": "[]",
    "extension_7eb927869ae04818b3aa16db92645c09_mfaTotpSecretKey": "32YZJFPXXOMHT237M64IVW63645GXQLV"
  },
  "DeletionTimestamp": null,
  ...
}
```

During the migration process from the old directory to the new Azure B2C directory, I also want to transfer the existing TOTP key so users don't need to reregister their TOTP key. I have spent all day to get this to work, but no luck and I really don't know what's left.

I have created an app registration in the tenant with `Directory.ReadWrite.All` rights, but when I read the user, then the extension is empty:

```cs
var creds = new ClientSecretCredential("<tenant-id>", "<client-id>", "<client-secret>", new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud });
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(creds, new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
var user = await graphClient.Users["<object-id>"].Request().Select(u => new {u.Id, u.Extensions}).Expand(u => new { u.Extensions}).GetAsync();
```

If I can't read the value, then I probably can't write it. I tried using *OpenTypeExtension*, but I am under the impression that this is a completely different property.

I can't find any documentation that tells me how I can run `Get-AzureADUser` using Graph API v2 in C#.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there three possible ways to extend properties in Azure AD for an object:

1. [AzureAD Graph extension attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0)
2. [Azure AD Open extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview#open-extensions)
3. [Azure AD Schema extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview#schema-extensions)

Azure B2C uses [AzureAD Graph extension attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0) and these should be fetched directly on the user object like this:

```cs
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(...);
var user = await graphClient.Users["<object-id>"].Request().Select("extension_7eb927869ae04818b3aa16db92645c09_mfaTotpSecretKey").GetAsync();
var mfaTotpSecretKey = user.AdditionalData["extension_7eb927869ae04818b3aa16db92645c09_mfaTotpSecretKey"]?.ToString();
```

When the user is created, then these properties can be added to the `AdditionalData` property of the user.

Note that Azure B2C uses the persistent claim name `extension_mfaTotpSecretKey`, but this is translated to `extension_<client-id-without-hyphens>_mfaTotpSecretKey`, where `<client-id>` is the client-id of the B2C extensions app (with all hyphens removed).

Answer (score 1):

**Extension attributes are not included by default if you use the v1 endpoint of the Microsoft Graph**. You must explicitly ask for them via a `$select`, as per @Ramon answer. When you use a `$select` statement, you'll get back only the specified attributes plus the id, so pay attention and specify all the fields you need. Moreover, **the SDK is misleading since you'll find the extension attributes under the `AdditionalData` field, not in the `Extensions` field.**

When you are going to migrate the users to a new tenant, keep in mind that the extension attribute name will change since the middle part is the b2c-extensions appId without the dashes.
i.e.

on Tenant 1: `extension_xxx_myAttribute`

on Tenant 2: `extension_yyy_myAttribute`

When you'll try to write the extension attribute on Tenant 2 via Microsoft Graph it must already exist. If you never run your custom policies on the new tenant you can create the attribute via Microsoft Graph as well with a simple POST operation:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<b2c-extensions-app-objectId/extensionProperties
{
   "name": "attributeName",
   "dataType":"string/int/etc.",
   "targetObjects": ["User"]
}
```

You'll get the full extension attribute name in the response (i.e. `extension_xxx_attributeName`)

HTH, F.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var extensionProperties = await graphClient.Applications["{application-id}"].ExtensionProperties
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: There is no link to the 'object-id', so how can it get the secret key of this particular user?